# Ubuntu 21.04 - Dummy Output only on Lenovo Flex 5i Chromebook

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, chromebook, soundcard, speakers

this is my first time posting so please be gentle, it's been a while since I was in the Ubuntu ecosystem, and I'm very much an old noob!

I have a new Lenovo Flex 5i Chromebook (i3 model), which I understand may not be very well supported being so new. Certianly suspend/resume doesn't work and I haven't delved into the non-functional touchscreen, but for now, I can live without both of these features.

What I'm struggling with though, is the lack of sound through speakers/headphones, as the soundcard doesn't seem to be detected. I did have some luck getting the headphone jack to work tinkering with alsamixer when I installed Manjaro KDE, as it recognised the soundcard as a CAVs Comet Lack PCH card, with an option for DAC/ADC that gave me headphone out.

Bluetooth audio out and USB c headphones audio out and mic-in both work perfectly, however, absolutely no luck thus far with Ubuntu 21.04 and the inbuilt speakers and microphone. I've tried the dmic_detect=0 option in grub and alsa.conf from other post suggestions, and a bunch of other suggestions I've found on the forums here, but so far, nothing seems to actually detect the card. I'm feeling like it should be physically possible given the ability of Manjaro to output sound through the headphone jack. I understand it's possible that the device is simply too new and too unsupported being a Chromebook, but I'm wondering if anyone else has had any luck with a device that runs similar hardware.

The output of alsa-info is here if that's of any use : http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=28a9bcccb179ed5c9856cc19d9ea4970111f9348

Please let me know if the output of any other commands may be useful.

Any assistance would be enormously appreciated, I've hit my knowledge and research limit!

Many thanks, Josh.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the similar issues with my Logitech M535 bluetooth mouse on a HP 2020  14t laptop running Ubuntu 21.04 after coming out of suspend mode.  Bluetooth is integrated on the Realtech RTL8821ce wireless/bluetooth chip on this laptop.  I also had wireless issues with Parted Magic version 20-10 and earlier on this laptop.  I will check if Parted Magic version 21-05 has issues with bluetooth when suspending.

My current workaround to get bluetooth running is to hibernate my laptop using 'sudo systemctl hibernate' and then rebooting.

Comment: Hi Mark, 

Bluetooth works well for me, though the toggle switch and sustemctl and another terminal command I don't remember right now don't work properly and require a reboot the same as you. For me that's an issue I can live with. 

I think I'm resigned to the fact that suspend/resume will likely never work as it's not a priority for devs and that audio might work in a few years. Probably will have a new device by then and just go back to ChromeOS on the Lenovo, which is a shame, because Ubuntu is properly fantastic and significantly faster than ChromeOS.

Comment: I read on the Facebook Group Ubuntu that they are aware of the issue and should be resolved on the next release.  I have disabled suspend when on AC power and upgraded my Logitech mouse to a M585 which can run on either USB or Bluetooth  from two seperate channels to different computers.